# Verify parameters using Arg.parse in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Right now I'm able to check if I pass two parameters (both being integers from the height and width of a maze) and I wish to add flags before them, respectively `-r` (for rows) and `-c` (for columns).

Here'e what I have so far:

```
let usage = "[Usage]:\t./step -r height -c width"

let row = ref "-r"
let column = ref "-c"
let height = ref (-1)
let width = ref (-1)

let main () =
  begin
    Arg.parse [] (fun i ->
      if !height < 0
      then height := (int_of_string i)
      else width := (int_of_string i)) usage;
  end

let _ = main ()
```

Even after reading documentation about `Arg.parse` I'm not able to figure out how to add a verification to have the full format (`-r height -c width`) passed as parameter to my executable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am learning OCaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar of a command line interface is specified by the first argument of the `parse` function. The second argument is a function that is called for each anonymous argument occurring on the command line, i.e., an argument that doesn't have a key before it.  Here is the example:

```
Arg.parse Arg.[
  "-r", Set_int height, "<height> set height";
  "-c", Set_int width,  "<width>  set width";
] ignore usage
```